# BATCH if two textfiles are not the same, copy both into new textfile

Tags: batch-file

So i got a program which exports the current Song out of a game into a text file.
Now i want to have 2 files, 1 with the current song output and 1 with the old output which gets updated when the song isn't the same in both files so in the old output file there should be:

```
song2  
song1
```

and in the current output file:

```
song2
```

Kinda hard to explain.
I tried it like that:

```
for /f "tokens=* USEBACKQ" %%f in (`findstr "Now Playing:" np.txt`) DO (  
    set var=%%f
)  
echo %var%  
for /f "tokens=* USEBACKQ" %%f in (`findstr "Now Playing:" lastplayed.txt`) DO (  
    set var1=%%f  
)  
echo %var1% 
if %var% NOT %var1%
copy %var% + %var1% justplayed.txt
```

Please don't be rude to me, i'm totally new to BATCH and just tried my best.
And if i messed up completely, please correct me.

Thank You in advance.

Comment: In your code, you have three text files: `np.txt`, `lastplayed.txt`, and `justplayed.txt`.  Was that a mistake, or do you need all three to exist?

Answer (score 0):

```
...
echo %var1% 
if "%var%" NEQ "%var1%" copy "%var%" + "%var1%" justplayed.txt
```

This should work, assuming that you are getting `%var%` and `%var`% displayed correctly.

The filename is quted on both sides of the comparison opreator so that if either of the variables contains a separator (like space) then the string is interpreted as a single item. Same comment goes for the `copy` command. The `neq` operator means `not equal`. Note that it is essential to put the target command on the same line as the `if`. The format is quite strict and *can* be spread across multiple lines if you desire, but in that case it **must** follow the following format:

```
if something operator somethingelse (
 dothis
) else (
 dothat
)
```

where operator must be one of **==** **equ** **neq** **gtr** **lss** **geq** **leq** ; the `else` clause is optional and the close-parenthesis may be on the same line as the matching open-parenthesis if you like.